# MySQL call SHOW ERRORS after executing a stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I have several stored procedures that I am calling via PDO in PHP. I was hoping to be able to handle errors by performing a ROLLBACK, but I still want to be able to use PHP to retrieve and handle the last error in the procedure. I have tryed using PDO::errorCode() and PDO::errorInfo(), but that does seem to be a legitimate solution, I think because I am already handling the errors in my stored procedures.

When I call one of the stored procedures via command line and then call SHOW ERRORS I get a nice result set with the error status, code and message, but if I call SHOW ERRORS in PDO after executing the stored procedure, I get no results. I also get no result from SHOW ERRORS in command line if I call show errors inside the stored procedure.

I would use GET DIAGNOSTICS, but the MySQL server I am developing for is on a hosted cPanel that I don't have control over updating and it is version 5.5.

Is there some other option I could use or another route I should be taking?

Like I said, I have several stored procedures I want to handle errors, but I can't even get this to work on a simple stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
END;

SELECT *
FROM bunnies;
END
```

**Update:** My PHP code was in an object, so I copied and simplified the code to post per Barmar's request and when I tried the simplified code, I found that SHOW ERRORS does indeed work with PDO when prepared and executed after the function is prepared and executed.

My object was a little complicated (I wrote it a while back before I knew much about PHP OOP), so I simplified it as well and now it works! I think the connection was being closed in between calls and now that the code is simpler, I am having no problems with calling SHOW ERRORS in it.

Here's the simplified PHP code I used to test, in case anyone has had issues getting this to work:

```
    $host = '***';
    $user = '***';
    $pass = '***';
    $schema = '***';

    $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $schema . ';', $user, $pass);
    $statement = $connection->prepare('CALL test()');
    $statement->execute();
    $statement = $connection->prepare('SHOW ERRORS');
    $statement->execute();
    echo var_dump($statement->fetchAll());

    $statement = null;
    $statement = null;
    $connection = null;
```

Comment: I think it should work with PDO -- show your code. The only thing I can think of is that you're starting a new connection between the procedure call and `SHOW ERRORS`, so you're losing state.

Comment: Thanks Barmar! I have posted an update above and SHOW ERRORS works correctly as you said. How can I mark you as having answered it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use the same PDO connection object to execute the original queries and to retrieve the errors. Each connection has its own error state.